# Python prefetch_related doesn't cache data

Tags: python, sql, django, caching

Here is my problem :

I have two tables on a foreign database who look like this :

```
class cell(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=36)   

class specs(models.Model):
    value_str = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    linked = models.ForeignKey(cell, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

So cell has multiple specs pointing at him.
I'm running a query to get some cells with their specs :

```
cells = cell.objects.using('db_name').prefetch_related('specs_set').all()
```

After this query I have a "for" for each cell where I need to use some specs object :

```
for cell in cells :
    print(cell.reference)
    spec = cell.specs_set.filter(name='spec_name').first()
    print(spec.value_str)
```

This works, but by my understanding of prefetch_related, the specs objects should be cached thanks to the first query and therefore I should not have to run another query at each iteration to get my "spec_name".

Just to be sure, I ran a Wireshark on my laptop and ... surprise ... a query is made on each iteration :(
So I have the first query that return all cells - and for every cell I have a new query that gets the wanted specs. The first one is ok, but all the following is a problem for me and they should not be there.

**My question :**
What have I done wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefetch related uses only if you need all instances, but this does not work if you need to filter it. For example:

```
for cell in cells :
    print(cell.reference)
    spec = cell.specs_set.all()
    print(spec.value_str)
```

This will work

but if you need:

```
for cell in cells :
    print(cell.reference)
    spec = cell.specs_set.filter(name='spec_name').first()
    print(spec.value_str)
```

this won't work.

See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

for filterring you should use Prefetch like so:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

qs = cpecs.objects.filter(name='spec_name')

cells = cell.objects.using(
    'db_name'
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('specs_set', queryset=qs)
).all()
```

See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects

I do not know about first, I think this won't work with first, but you can use:

```
list(cell.specs_set.filter(name='spec_name'))[0]
```

instead of first or try something else